# lualatex: Why is \textbar̈ working, but not \textbar̙?

Tags: luatex, unicode, combine

Why is line b) working, but not line d), if compiled the with lualatex?

In Line b) the r (U+0072) is followed by ̈ (U+0308). This compiles without errors.

In Line d) the r (U+0072) is followed by ̙ (U+0319). This produces (if `%` removed) the error “\textbar̙ … Undefined control sequence. …”

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{dejavu-otf}
\begin{document}
a) r̙ r̈ \$̈ \$̙
b) \textbar̈
c) \textbar{}̙
d) % \textbar̙
\end{document}
```

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020/Debian)
```

Comment: The exact error is that `\textbar̙` is undefined. The U+0319 has the catcode of a letter, and so continues the command name, you get an error for the same reason why you would get an error from `\textbarx`: the command name simply isn't defined.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes that's clear but what happened with the first one that is using r followed by U+0308 which is also catcode 11 but `\show\textbar̈` shows `\textbar` with the diacritic following, as if it were catcode 12 ?

Comment: oh it is catcode 12, that seems... wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the  <strike>`dejavu-otf` package</strike> `unicode-math` it is making the combining diaeresis catcode12 (punctuation) so it can not be part of a command name

```
\showthe\catcode"0308
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\showthe\catcode"0308
%\usepackage{dejavu-otf}
\showthe\catcode"0308
\begin{document}
\showthe\catcode"0308

a) r̙ r̈ \$̈ \$̙
b) \show\textbar̈
c) \textbar{}̙
d)  \show\textbar̙
\end{document}
```

adding `\catcode"0308=11` would restore the usual behaviour.

---

This seems to be a feature of `unicode-math` (I'll raise it there)

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{unicode-math}
\showthe\catcode"0308
\setmathfont{TeXGyreDejaVuMath-Regular}
\showthe\catcode"0308
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

just setting the math font changes the catcode of a text diacritic which seems... unexpected

Comment: Reported as https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/566